# My current code receives an input which states how many fibonacci numbers is going to add up, but the output is wrong in one of the six test runs

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, fibonacci

The code basically receives one input which is the number of Fibonacci numbers that is going to add up. First, it generates the Fibonacci list with a for loop, and then with another for loop, it adds up the elements inside the said list.

I don't know what the problem is with the code since it's working fine with 6 test runs but there's one that is not giving the correct answer. The output my code is giving is '1', but apparently that's not correct and the test doesn't show me what the input is.

If anyone could help me by pointing out any mistakes or corrections it would be really helpful.

PS: I'm kind of new with python and coding as a whole, so if you could simplify complicated coding terms I would appreciate it :S

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the 'sumOfNFibonacciNumbers' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts INTEGER n as parameter.

def sumOfNFibonacciNumbers(n):
    n1,n2=0,1
    fib=[]
    s = 0
    
    if n <= 0:
        fib.append(0)
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        fib.append(1)
        return 1
    else:
        fib.append(0)
        fib.append(1)
        for i in range(2,n):
            x=fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]
            fib.append(x)
   
        for i in range(0,len(fib)):
            s = s + fib[i] 
        return(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input().strip())

    result = sumOfNFibonacciNumbers(n)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: What's the point of appending to `fib` in the first two cases, since you just return the known sum?

Comment: BTW, Python has a built-in `sum()` function, you don't have to write your own loop.

Comment: What are the `n1` and `n2` variables for?

Comment: The problem is supposed to be solved with a for loop, sorry for not clarifying that in the instructions, and the n1 and n2 are leftover variables from another way I was trying to write the code, again sorry for not taking them out.

Comment: Please clarify the values you have right and the values you get wrong, can't answer without that

Comment: There are eight test cases and out of those I only know two of the inputs (Test 0 and Test 1), all of the others are hidden but the outputs are as follow: [TestCase 0: Input=5, Output=7] [TestCase 1: Input=10, Output=88] [TestCase 2: Output: 10945] [TestCase 3: Output: 20365011073] [TestCase 4: Output: 573147844013817084100]  [TestCase 5: Output: 308061521170128] [TESTCASE 6: Output: 1] [TestCase 7: Output: 1]. The only output that is wrong is TestCase 6 and the only info I have about it is that my code gives out a '1' which is not correct. I hope that can clarify a bit.

Answer (score 2):

For now you have an incorrect result starting at index `2`, regarding fibonnaci values `0 1 1 2 3 5 8`

```
i=0 sum=0
i=1 sum=1
i=2 sum=1 should be 2
i=3 sum=2 should be 4
i=4 sum=4 should be 7
i=5 sum=7 should be 12
```

For loop should go to `n+1` so that interval is `[2;n]` (`n` included)

---

Then you can simplify a bit, removing the use of `fib` in first `if` cases, and use built-in `sum` then

```
def sumOfNFibonacciNumbers(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        fib = [0, 1]
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            fib.append(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2])
        return sum(fib)
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections!

I made the changes in my code but there are two things. The first one is that 'n+1' is changing the results a bit, so the answers are not coming out as correct. The input is supposed to tell the number of elements to be added from 0 onwards, so if the input is 5 it would add the values until the fifth one ''0,1,1,2,3,5,8'', which would be 3 in this case.

After I remove the '+1' from n, all test cases are correct except for the one that was initially wrong, so I think the problem is still there somewhere but I can´t figure out what is it.